Rails render: appending instead of replacing content
I am following this tutorial https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#creating-a-new-article, it shows how to add validation messages. But when I submit the form it is appending a new page under the old one!
controller class is like
  def new
    @article = Article.new
  end

  def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)

    if @article.save
      redirect_to @article
    else
      render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

So, after submit, when @article.save returns false it should just render again 'new page' with the error messages, but I get this:

What is wrong?

Can you post the contents of app/views/articles/new.html.erb

Is the same as the example https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#using-a-form-builder. But now, checking my files I just found out why. The file name instead of new.html.rb, I had just new.rb. I didn't see any warning about that, just the render was appending instead of replacing.
